# Removing default actionbar tab padding

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

My problem is that I can't seem to override androids default tab padding and it's making my tabs horizontally scrollable (which I don't want). I've searched around stack overflow and other sites online but i can't find a solution for my problem. I am using appcompat-v7 and I'm targeting api 21 with my minimum sdk set to api 14.

Here is my **themes**.**xml**

```
<style name="TSTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_blue_500</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_blue_500</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
</style>
```

I have tried adding **android:** prefix but it still doesn't do anything. I have also defined my custom theme in my manifest

Any and all help is much appreciated

Comment: try using  <style name="ActionBarTabStyle"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/no_padding</item>
</style>        <style name="no_padding"> <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item><item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item> </style>

Comment: I just tried this, I'm still facing the same problem

Comment: Any solution that worked ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to create your own style and then you can set that style to actionbar manually. This is the only way to make it done.

```
 <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>


<style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```